# Running a Function with Arguments using Multiprocessing, and Storing the Result

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Say I have a program that contains a simulation-based function which takes some time to compute.

```
def foo_func(args):
    # some calculations
    return foo  # df


res = {}  # will be a dictionary of dfs
for i in range(n):
    res[i] = foo_func(args)
```

**Problem:** Calculating foo using foo_func **n times** takes too long

**Question:** how do i implement multiprocessing/multithreading within the program, and store the results in res?

Note that:

- foo_func takes in args
- order does **not** matter within the res - the order in which the jobs finish does not matter, as long as all of the jobs are correctly stored in res

Comment: you can take a look at how to create threads in python (there are lots of tutorials with nice code explanations out there). Then supposing you have 4 threads, divide your range in 4 equal parts and assign to each thread a range to calculate and generate their own dictionary. Then at the end you can easily merge the dictionaries, since each will have different keys.

Comment: You can take a look at celery https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Comment: Managed to actually fix my issue by improving the running time of foo_func itself (using np.vectorize), but i have read about both of your suggestions and learnt a lot, thanks! @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: In your posted code you appear to be calling `foo_func` repeatedly with unchanging *args* argument(s). Is that right?